# magento 1.9 Add video in email templates

Tags: magento-1.7, transactional-mail

Does anyone know how to add video in email template

I am working on transactional email template in Magento.
I want to add video in my email template.
I have added using an iframe. But it's not showing in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add video in email template

`<iframe>'s` cannot be used in most email clients – whether in an application or as a website. They are either stripped for one of several reasons:

The mail/web client could have trouble rendering it, so it is excluded.

A `<iframe>` could be used for phishing/malicious attacks, putting malicious code in what was otherwise vetted and safe (the browser/client can't see or scan what gets loaded into an iframe, it just loads it into the DOM).

An alternative, (what YouTube do), is instead of embedding something in an iframe (in their case, a video), they have a  wrapped around an  or thumbnail, which gives the impression that you are playing a video. All it does when you click on it is it takes you to that video's URL.